# Persistent boot order not happening after rescue and reboot from CD-ROM mounted ISO in RHEL 7.4

Tags: rhel, boot, vmware, iso

I mount the RHEL 7.4 ISO available in the CD-ROM and go into the rescue mode (Troubleshooting) after selecting CD-ROM option in the "One-time Boot menu". And, after reboot it is supposed to boot back to the installed OS. But in RHEL7.4 the booting is still happening from the CD and the OS installation screen is displayed instead of login screen. In, RHEL7.3 it is working as expected, persistent boot menu order is prevailed after reboot.

I am now clueless about what has been changed from RHEL 7.3 to 7.4 related to boot menu/grub boot order.

Comment: **I mount the RHEL 7.4 ISO available in the CD-ROM** - Are you using a CD-ROM or a ISO file, cause it isn't clear. If you are using a CD-ROM, it's a matter of boot order of your Motherboard, not an OS issue...

Comment: @nwildner I mount the RHEL ISO in the CD-ROM via VM console. Hope now its clear to you